# Does the covariance matrix of a multivariate normal distribution have to be positive definite?

Tags: normal-distribution, covariance

Let $\Sigma $ be the covariance matrix of a multivariate normal
distribution.

Thereotically, I guess it does not have to to strictly positive definition,
i.e., $\det (\Sigma )=0$ is possible.

In this case, the density function does not exist, how can I generate random
numbers(vectors) from such multivariate normal distribution?

Comment: To simulate $X$ with covariance $\Sigma$ or size $n$ and rank $k$, choose $L$ of size $n\times k$ such that $\Sigma=LL^T$, simulate $U$ standard normal of size $k$ and use $X=LU$.

Comment: @MANMAID "so I am not sure, if this works or not" Or not.

Comment: Solution for generating random vectors for a singular Multivariate Normal is at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63817/generate-normally-distributed-random-numbers-with-non-positive-definite-covarian .

Comment: If $\det (\Sigma )=0$ your distribution is supported on a subspace. Pick rank ⁡$( Σ )$ coordinates on which the covariance is non-degenerate and express the rest as their affine functions. Then generate the picked coordinates the usual way and use those functions to compute the rest.

Answer (score 0):

A multivariate normal distribution has the density function:

$$f(X) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^n |\Sigma|}} \exp\{\frac{-1}{2}X \Sigma^{-1} X^T\}$$

and the covariance should be positive definite.
So if you need multivariate normal samples you've got to generate them using a valid (meaning symmetric positive definite) covariance matrix.
But then, when you generated the random vectors, the calculated sample covariance can be not positive definite. As an example, consider a covariance matrix of rank 10. If you generate less than 10 sample vectors (i.e. 1 to 9 samples), and calculate their sample covariance, the calculated covariance matrix is not full rank, and its determinant becomes 0, although the generative model has a valid positive definite covariance.

Comment: " if you need multivariate normal samples you've got to generate them using a valid covariance matrix." This is only true if "valid" is interpreted to mean symmetric positive semidefintie, which was clearly not intended in the context in which it appears.. See my comment above.

Comment: Yeah. I should define valid, but it is symmetric positive definite; P.S.D is not the definition of multivariate normal. And if the issue is about making a distribution from sample covariance (as indicated in your link), you have to use techniques to correct the covariance and define the distribution. I refer you to Sigma algebra to check the need for the distribution.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible approach. Suppose that $X\sim N(0,\Sigma)$. We have that
$$
\Sigma=Q\Lambda Q^{\mathrm T},
$$
where $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix with the eigenvectors of $\Sigma$ as its columns and $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of $\Sigma$ on its diagonal (this is the eigendecomposition or the spectral decomposition of $\Sigma$). Generate $Z\sim N(0,I)$. Then $Q\Lambda^{1/2}Z\sim N(0,\Sigma)$, where $\Lambda^{1/2}$ is the square root of $\Lambda$ obtained by taking the square roots of the eigenvalues on the diagonal. Indeed,
$$
\operatorname E[(Q\Lambda^{1/2}Z)(Q\Lambda^{1/2}Z)^{\mathrm T}]
=\operatorname E[Q\Lambda^{1/2}ZZ^{\mathrm T}\Lambda^{1/2}Q^{\mathrm T}]
=Q\Lambda^{1/2}I\Lambda^{1/2}Q^{\mathrm T}
=Q\Lambda Q^{\mathrm T}=\Sigma.
$$
The eigendecomposition of $\Sigma$ can by obtained using the $\texttt{eigen}()$ function in $\texttt R$.

I hope this is helpful.